# Edit data with php

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I edit my database on php, it said I success editing my data, but when I check on my sql database, It's not change yet ...

here is the code

```
<?php
$koneksi = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Gagal konek ke  server.");
mysql_select_db("kasatrian") or die("Gagal membuka database.");
$nis = isset($_GET['nis']) ? $_GET['nis'] :null;
$query = "select * from siswa where nis='$nis'";
$hasil = mysql_query($query, $koneksi) or die("Gagal melakukan query.");
$buff = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
    mysql_close($koneksi);?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit2.php">
<input type="hidden" name="nis" value="<?php echo $buff['nis']; ?>" />
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><center><font size=5>EDIT DATA SISWA</font></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nama</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="nama" value="<?php echo $buff['nama']; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=2></td>
<td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Simpan" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>Batal mengedit data. Kembali ke <a href="datasiswa.php">Data Siswa</a></p>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is the edit process

```
<?php
$koneksi = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Gagal konek ke server.");

mysql_select_db("kasatrian") or die("Gagal membuka database.");

$nama = isset($_POST['nama']) ? $_POST['nama']: " ";

$query = mysql_query("update siswa set 
nama='$nama' where nis='$nis' ");

mysql_close($koneksi);

?>

<p>Data sudah ter-update. Silakan dicek di <a href="datasiswa.php">data siswa</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

the code said it already save, but when I check my DB on SQL, nothing change.

Comment: *"my code is not working - here is my code"* is not a good question... show some effort and track the bug down and post the relevant code and a specific question.

Comment: In your edit process code write  `$nis= isset($_POST['nis']) ? $_POST['nis']: " ";` just after `$nama` declaration and then try?  Also you are not executing your query so execute it. thanks

Comment: this my entire code 
i upload it on dropbox, here the link if you guys dont mind
process edit : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bt5zz5je9l475g/edit2.php?dl=0
edit : https://www.dropbox.com/s/l08cn55cmoia315/edit.php?dl=0